# Animate multiple sprites in libgdx screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a small game in libgdx, and I would like to animate more characters on the screen. I know how to animate a single character, but considering for example 5 characters, I wouldn't know how to animate all of them. Can anyone give me some advice? For now the characters are inside an array. My array is:

```
    public void makeCharacters() {
    characters = new Array<Characters>();
    characters.add(new Characters(new Sprite(new Texture("img1.png")), spawn));
    characters.add(new Characters(new Sprite(new Texture("img2.png")), spawn));
    characters.add(new Characters(new Sprite(new Texture("img3.png")), spawn));
    characters.add(new Characters(new Sprite(new Texture("img4.png")), spawn));
    characters.add(new Characters(new Sprite(new Texture("img5png")), spawn));
```

Comment: Please add more details and be a little more specific: What is "Characters" and what do you mean with "animate"?

Answer (score 0):

if your characters have a `draw()` function

```
for(Characters c: characters){ c.draw() }
```

Otherwise I do it like this

```
 class Characters{
   public SpriteBatch batch;
   public TextureRegion[] regions; //create array of texture
   public Animation<TextureRegion> animation;

   public Characters(String relative_path, int tileWidth, int tileHeight){
     batch =  new SpriteBatch();
     // I take into consideration that you use an image so probably a sprite sheet.
     regions = TextureRegion.split(new Texture(relative_path), tileWidth, tileHeight)[0];
     animation = new Animation<>(frameDuration, regions);
   }

   public void draw(float elapse){
      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapse, `loop` : true),x,y,width,height);
      batch.end();
   }
   
 }

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Characters characters = new Array<Characters>();

    @Override
    public void create () {
      //width/height of a frame not the entire image
      characters.add("img1.png", width, height);
      characters.add("img2.png", width, height);
      characters.add("img3.png", width, height);
      characters.add("img4.png", width, height);
      characters.add("img5.png", width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        elapse += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        for(Characters c: characters ){
          c.draw(elapse);
        }

    }
}
```

it is lot of code but hope its helping.